# //java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application (JSTL lib added but does not workin)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I have gradle java spring project.
spring 3 ,Tomcat 7 , Jdk 1.8 .

Project run local machine but does not working on test server.

checked jstl lib and added.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: which part of code?

Comment: web.xml code file

Comment: Also, what test server you are using

Comment: test server Jboss

Comment: web.xml  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Servlet 2.4 Web Application</display-name>

Comment: As it is currently written, your post is unclear and can hardly be answered. What do you mean by "not working"? Which error occurs? Where? Please edit your question and add the relevant portions of the code. Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

try this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>  
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks but checked jstl lib and added. Project old version now using JSTL but ı have try jst 1.2 same error :/

Comment: try to remove the version it might help

Comment: My project not maven , gradle project